# Merge multidimensional PHP array by [i][1] key, then redefine the top level index to be that key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

The starting point is this multi-dimensional array that we have:

```
<?php
$crime = array(
    array(
        "suspect" => "1001",
        "weapon" => "knife",
        "vehicle" => "car"
    ) ,
    array(
        "suspect" => "1001",
        "weapon" => "nunchucks",
        "vehicle" => "skateboard"
    ) ,
    array(
        "suspect" => "1002",
        "weapon" => "gun",
        "vehicle" => "truck"
    ) ,
    array(
        "suspect" => "1002",
        "weapon" => "baseball bat",
        "vehicle" => "car"
    ) ,
    array(
        "suspect" => "1003",
        "weapon" => "knife",
        "vehicle" => "bus"
    )
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($crime);
echo '</pre>';
```

I want to merge my arrays by the suspect value.

We have some suspects with multiple arrays, so for example Suspect `1001` has `$crime[0]` and `$crime[1]`, other suspects may have more than 2 arrays, and some just one:

```
$crime=
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1001
            [weapon] => knife
            [vehicle] => car
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1001
            [weapon] => nunchucks
            [vehicle] => skateboard
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1002
            [weapon] => gun
            [vehicle] => truck
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1002
            [weapon] => baseball bat
            [vehicle] => car
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1003
            [weapon] => knife
            [vehicle] => bus
        )

)
```

I want to consolidate these arrays to this effect - which will result in an irregular structure but the goal is to have one array for each suspect only:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1001
            [weapon] => Array
                (
                    [0] => knife
                    [1] => nunchucks
                )

            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => car
                    [1] => skateboard
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1002
            [weapon] => Array
                (
                    [0] => gun
                    [1] => baseball bat
                )

            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => truck
                    [1] => car
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [suspect] => 1003
            [weapon] => knife
            [vehicle] => bus
        )

)
```

Now that each suspect has a unique array, we may as well change the top level index to be associative using `suspect` number as the key:

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
        (
            [weapon] => Array
                (
                    [0] => knife
                    [1] => nunchucks
                )

            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => car
                    [1] => skateboard
                )

        )

    [1002] => Array
        (
            [weapon] => Array
                (
                    [0] => gun
                    [1] => baseball bat
                )

            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => truck
                    [1] => car
                )

        )

    [1003] => Array
        (
            [weapon] => knife
            [vehicle] => bus
        )

)
```

Please offer an elegant solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($crime as $item) {
    $suspectId = $item['suspect'];
    if (empty($grouped[$suspectId])) {
        $grouped[$suspectId] = [
            'weapon' => [],
            'vehicle' => [],
        ];
    }

    $grouped[$suspectId]['weapon'][] = $item['weapon'];
    $grouped[$suspectId]['vehicle'][] = $item['vehicle'];
}
```

Variant for any keys:

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($crime as $item) {
    $suspectId = $item['suspect'];
    if (empty($grouped[$suspectId])) {
        $grouped[$suspectId] = [];
    }
    unset($item['suspect']);
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($grouped[$suspectId][$key])) {
            $grouped[$suspectId][$key] = [];
        }
        $grouped[$suspectId][$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising.  Forgive me, but I'm rather new to PHP programming, why this condition `if (empty($grouped[$suspectId]))`?  So you are testing if `$grouped[$suspectId])` is empty?  Can you explain the reasoning?

Comment: I check for empitness because new subarray should be added to `$grouped` only __once__.